# Cannot mount new dvd, old dvd's work

Tags: mount, dvd

I can mount any (?) dvd that I have looked at before. If I buy an new DVD, and try to watch it, I cannot mount it. Sometimes ejecting the DVD and inserting it again 20 times or so helps. This is odd.

---

My output of dmesg is as follows:

marc@ultima-thule:~$ dmesg -T | grep dvd
[Fri Feb 18 17:17:42 2022] sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[Fri Feb 18 17:18:32 2022] pktcdvd: pktcdvd0: writer mapped to sr0

---

Edit : Following up on a comment, the output of smartctl is as follows :

Vendor:               TSSTcorp
Product:              CDDVDW SH-224BB
Revision:             SB00

> > Terminate command early due to bad response to IEC mode page

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging

Comment: What is it you want to do with the DVD? Watch it rip it?

Comment: Just watch it. Nothing else.

Comment: With what player?

Comment: VLC Media Player

Comment: You do not say what version of Ubuntu but all I have ever had to do since 16.04 up to and including 20.04 is. Insert disk start vlc and from vlc select disk. NEVER mount or try to access it from the file system.

Comment: Could be a dirty lens in the drive, and possibly an outdated firmware.  If it is reading older DVDs and not newer I would push more towards an outdated firmware.  `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sr0` should be able to show you the model and firmware version of your drive.

Comment: Looking at your code I have been able to find a SB01 revision that helps compatibility.  https://drivers.softpedia.com/get/DVD-BluRay-Media-Players/TSST/TSST-SH-224BB-ODD-Firmware-SB01.shtml  You might also want to run `sudo hdparm -i /dev/sr0` to make sure that your drive is correct.  From personal experience, flashing a drive with the wrong firmware can completely render the drive worthless.